# how to display multivalued fields in velocity

Tags: velocity

I want to display a multivalued field in velocity.

The field is extracted from the oracle database.

My problem is that it does not display the values per line. Rather it just wraps the rows one after the other instead of creating a new line for a new row.

The follow code is what I used:

```
<div>#field('BugDescription')</div>
```

how do I break it down, so it's more readable?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`#foreach`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#foreach-loop) directive to loop through the values of a collection.